# How to determine the conviction of a democratic vote using Polkadot API

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

When I cast a vote on a referendum with a value as

```js
let vote = { 
    Standard: {
      vote: {                                                                                                                           
        aye: true,                                                                                                                                                                      
        conviction: 'Locked4x',                                                                                                                                                              
      },
      balance: balance
    }
  };

  let unsub = await api.tx.democracy.vote(i, vote).signAndSend(payoutKey, ...);
```

Through the event I have extracted the following data

```json
[
AccountId32: 5HeM14aFJPKxi...vVyV7oX6rErJhN,
u32: 79,
{"_enum":{"Standard":"{"vote":"Vote","balance":"u128"}","Split":"{"aye":"u128","nay":"u128"}"}}: {"standard":{"vote":"0x01","balance":"0x0000000000000000c249fdd327780000"}}]
```

We realize that it does not contain the vote conviction.

I tried to look it up via `api.query.democracy.votingOf(accountId)`

But unfortunately, every vote returns the same value `{conviction: "Locked1x", vote: "Nay"}`

Even if the actual values are entirely different. Eg: conviction is `Locked4x` and vote is `Aye`

[image]

**The questions are**:

1. How to get the conviction value of a democratic vote?
2. Why does `api.query.democracy.votingOf` always return the same value `{conviction: "Locked1x", vote: "Nay"}`

Answer (score 1):

The api.query.democracy.votingOf  is the right way to get the conviction value, it should not always return the same value `{conviction: "Locked1x", vote: "Nay"}`

An example:

See this referendum on Polkadot: https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referendum/95

The address `1hbyB383QeqwGNAHj439MKSnx3JMM1fzrXMAPtNfn6v3Smz` has placed 10 DOT with a 6x Conviction (see below the image from Polkassembly)

With this code:

```
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io')
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const votesOf = await api.query.democracy.votingOf("1hbyB383QeqwGNAHj439MKSnx3JMM1fzrXMAPtNfn6v3Smz");
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(votesOf.toHuman())}`);
```

We get the list of votes, and we can see that in the referendum with id 95 it has voted `{"conviction":"Locked6x","vote":"Aye"}` :

```
{"Direct":{"votes":[["95",{"Standard":{"vote":{"conviction":"Locked6x","vote":"Aye"},"balance":"100,000,000,000"}}]],"delegations":{"votes":"0","capital":"0"},"prior":["0","0"]}}
```

[image]

To know what can be wrong with your response, which is the id of the referendum where you are voting? and the address of the voter? and in which network are you voting?